# The meaning of "surprising as it is to hear of it"

Tags: phrase-meaning

n: I'm lost.
n: Surprising as it is to hear of it.
I actually can imagine that it means "I'm surprised to hear that", but I don't understand such complex of "as it is to hear of it". I'm getting sweat of such complication. Could you decipher it?

Comment: Can you please reformat the question to make it legible? I'm having trouble reading it.

Answer (score 1):

> Surprising as it is to hear of it.

The above is a fragment rather than a sentence so I'll add some invented context, e.g.

*Surprising as it is to hear of it, Elvis is still alive and well.*

In the above sentence, the first 'it' is impersonal in a similar way to the 'it' in "It is raining."

The second 'it' refers to "Elvis is still alive and well."

We can paraphrase as follows:

Original: *Surprising as it is to hear of it, Elvis is still alive and well.*

Paraphrase: *Elvis is alive and well. It is surprising to hear of it (i.e. this fact).*

Does that explain it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of that phrase worded that way exactly (even that exact phrase isn't found on Google) but "as surprising as it is to hear that..." is somewhat common.

```
As surprising as it is to hear that you're pregnant, I'm happy for you.
```

I.e While the news comes as a surprise it's received with joy.

Comment: I'm surprised that Google doesn't show this phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it before. What I believe is that an "as" is silent in the beginning. *As surprising as it is to hear of it,......*

As the last answer also points out, it is indeed a fragment. And the second "it" does point to what follows next after this phrase.

Comment: Ok, I got it. "As" was the missing link.